# Need versus needs

Tags: grammar

Hi I want to say ' the families have a high level of need'. However is it a high level of needs or high level of need. I think its need but am having a debate.

Comment: "Need". Couldn't tell you why, but as a native speaker that's what I'd say.

Comment: Level of need is singular

Comment: It’s possible you’re really trying to say *have many needs*. In general it might be easier to say *deprived* or *poor*, unless it’s more about, say, educational (“special”) needs.

Answer (score 1):

Statistically, 'high level of need' is much more popular, see the comparison diagram (Figure 1). According to my personal experience, 'level of' us normally used to describe uncountable abstract nouns, and it is proved by another statistical plot, see Figure 2.

Figure 1 
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2, the top ten nouns used in books following 'level of'
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While it is low-level acceptable to say "needs" if you wish to pluralize it, it will still sound strange anyway and "need" will be correct regardless of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a high level of *need*. Need implies there's more than one thing that the person is deficient in. Saying needs is really not necessary in this situation from my experience.